# How to connect Django Rest API to a html CSS JS frontend

Tags: javascript, django-rest-framework

I am new to programming and one thing I am very confused about, my boss has told me to create a rest API about an app which I have completed all the signups, login, and other parts. But now I have to create a frontend but all the tutorials on the internet are about create rest API of Django to react or some other frontend framework, is their any tutorial on YouTube about connecting to a html CSS JavaScript on frontend to Rest API. thanks.

Comment: after implementing your Api's, you only need to open CORS for the special port like 3000, and serve your front on that port(3000), then call your API calls in front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want a frontend just follow the official django tutorial to learn how to serve html/css/js from django.

From there you can either pass the data you need from your api down through the django context, or you can use `fetch` or something similar to grab it from javascript.

The latter would look like this.

```
# views.py
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def apiview(request):
    return JsonResponse({'title', 'served from api'})
```

```
index.html
<div class="title" token={{csrf_token}}></div>
<script>
function getTitle() {
    const div = document.querySelector('title')
    const csrf_token = div.getAttribute('token')
    fetch('localhost:8000/apiview', {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': token}
    })
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(data => div.innerHTML = data.title)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect, this is what I am looking for so If the app is on a medium scale how to structure this project, because I have an idea of working with django apps but dont know how to structure js projects.

Comment: That's a bit beyond scope of a SO question. I would watch a few javascript tutorials and then a few django tutorials to see how everything fits together. gl!

Comment: @MusicCause Did you later complete the project and did you find any tutorial?